# Compiler error using Swift #selector() to reference protocol method in target/action

Tags: swift, events, protocols, target, uicontrol

I have a custom UIControl and want to add targets for specific UIControlEvents. So I specified a protocol and a delegate variable in my custom UIControl:

```
protocol FieldEventHandlerDelegate {
    func willSelectField(sender:Field)
}

class Field {
    var delegate:FieldEventHandlerDelegate?

    func setupEventHandlers(withDelegate del:FieldEventHandlerDelegate) {
        delegate = del
        self.addTarget(delegate, action: #selector(willSelectField(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

But Xcode gives me the error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'willSelectField(sender:)'`